# When will ubuntu fully support high resolution displays

Tags: display, resolution, dpi

I've tried tinkering with font sizes in the unity-tweak-tool and changing the scale in the display but have been unable to find a workable solution.

Will there be proper support for this in the future? If so when can I expect it? I'd love to start using ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

Unity, the default desktop for Ubuntu, does not have much option for scaling displays. Since 14.04 however, you should be able to adjust the scaling of the launcher and panel in Settings:
[image: Look in the Display settings for 'Scale for menu and title bars']

In the 'Apperance' settings as well, you can change the icon size in the launcher.

You may also want to try [Gnome shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/65223/178596), as that has had support for high-res displays [since 3.10](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.10/more-core-ux.html.en#high-dpi). You should be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

You may want to install other packages as well for full functionality

Comment: If you have multiple displays: Use `Scale all window contents to match`, select a suiting alternative to use as a reference, then adjust scaling factor for each display - as shown above. It isn't perfect but you can get close (adjustment is in steps of 1/8th).

Comment: @Hannu 's suggestion does not seem to help: "then adjust scaling factor for each display - as shown above." The problem is that "Scale for menu and title bars" does not scale the window contents.